# Word 2010 Macros running on my computer but nobody else's

Tags: vba, merge, ms-word, macros

Most of the macros I build for Word essentially run a mail merge, make a copy of the document, then close down the original.  We recently upgraded to Office 2010, and since then, the macros I write will run on my machine, but nobody else's (the documents are stored on a shared drive).

I have checked the other user's Trust Center Settings, and they are set to allow macros.  I got on someone else's computer and went through the Designer tab to view the VB macro, and I could see the code.  The code did not run upon opening though, and I went to File>Info, but couldn't see the "Enable Content" button.  It's like it's not even registering that there is a macro.

I tried saving it as .doc and .docm, both work on my computer but not on anyone else's.  Old documents that I've created with macros still work on other people's computers, just not the ones I've created in Word 2010.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Todd. When you wrote these macros did they get recorded to the Normal template, or are they are in their own module? E.g. using the macro recorder will by default record to the Normal template.

Comment: Looking at the VBA window, I see three Projects: Normal, Project(MOA_KARD) and TemplateProject(ContributeWordUITemplate).  I wrote the code under Project(MOA_KARD)>Microsoft Word Objects>ThisDocument.

Comment: Try moving your code to a new module. Hard to tell, but sounds like it's part of your word configuration.

Comment: I just tried copying an old macro document into the shared drive, and when I opened it from my co-worker's computer, it ran the macro.  Then I copied JUST THE TEXT from my new document to the copy, and saved it.  Went to my co-workers computer and it wouldn't run the code.  It has something to do with what Word 2010 changes when it saves the document.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think it's the code.  The same code works in several other documents saved in an older version of Word.   

Private Sub Document_Open()

Me.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
Name:="c:\DataSources\KYFDGOLDLGS GOLD_ProjectONESQL.odc", _
Connection:="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" & _
"Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=GOLD_ProjectONESQL;data source=KYFDGOLDLGS;", _
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM [TblTEMP_MOA_EECBG]", _
subType:=wdMergeSubTypeOther

Me.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
Me.MailMerge.Execute
Me.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges

Comment: Please update the question with the code

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: You need to use the [edit] link to update your question with the code...

Comment: Please test: Add a normal module to a .docm file you create on your machine. In that module, add a `Sub` that simply shows a `MsgBox`. Will that run on another machine? (Note that you need to manually run it - we're just testing whether a macro *will* run.) If it runs, add another procedure with the name AutoOpen: `Sub AutoOpen` and display a `MsgBox`. This should run when the document is opened - does it? If not, check the file name in the Word title bar if it's the docm file name or something like "Document 1" which would indicate Word is creating a copy, rather than opening the file.

Comment: AH! Thank you Cindy!  Your guidance helped me solve the problem, it actually took three steps.  First, I saved the document as a .docm (instead of .doc).  Second, I changed the Sub from "Private Sub" to just "Sub".  Finally, I changed the name of the sub from "Document_Open()" to "AutoOpen()".  Now everything works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually took three steps. First, I saved the document as a .docm (instead of .doc). Second, I changed the Sub from "Private Sub" to just "Sub". Finally, I changed the name of the sub from "Document_Open()" to "AutoOpen()". Now everything works as it's supposed to.